# Configure C program in kate editor

Tags: debugging, configuration, compilation, kate

I want to build and run C program in kate editor ,can you please help me to solve this ,i need configuration for my editor how i can do it.i didnt find any tutorial

Comment: Your question is by far too vague to get a good answer here. Do you want to use the Build plugin for this? Do you already have a Makefile or CMakeLists.txt to build your project? If not, you should first setup [a proper project structure](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/aenxzi/cmake_project_templates/).

Comment: yes i dit it thanks but still have the same problem'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Usually you create a build folder, then type `cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` or so, and then you can type `make`.